# Background image change from array of images on button click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button

I want to change the background image of my app on button click. I put the images in an array and selecting the background image randomly. Below is the code.

```
const background = [
  "image/2.png",
  "image/4.png",
  "image/9.png",
  "image/14.png",
  "image/12.png",
  "image/17.png",
];

function changeColor() {
  const getimage = `${
    background[Math.floor(Math.random() * background.length)]
  }`;
  document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundImage = 'url("getimage")';
  console.log(getimage);
}
```

The Console log shows that 'on button click' the *getimage* variable is changing randomly. But in the browser, the background is not changing! Not getting what am I missing?

Comment: Change the `backgroundImage` value to `url("`+getimage+")` or enclose the whole expression inside a template string like `\`url("${getimage}")\``

Answer (score 0):

When you set the style you are setting the url to `getimage` as a string instead of the element. To fix your problem, you just need to put it as the element, either as

``` document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundImage = `url("${getimage}")`;
// uses `` to include a variable using ${} ```

or:

`document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + getimage + '")'; // adds the variable in the middle of the string`

Answer (score 0):

Try interpolate getimage

```
document.querySelector("body").style.background = `url(${getimage})`;
```